# AppleScript choose from list

Tags: dialog, applescript

Very simple question but how to start a script from a "choose from List"

E.g :

```
set issueList to {"1", "2", "2", "4"}

set selectedIssue to {choose from list issueList}

if selectedIssue is {"1"} then
    display dialog "ok" buttons {"1"} default button 1
else if selectedIssue is {"Holds Charge"} then
    -- do nothing
    display dialog "ok" buttons {"2"} default button 1
else if selectedIssue is {"2"} then
    -- do nothing
    display dialog "ok" buttons {"3"} default button 1
else if selectedIssue is {"3"} then
    -- do nothing   
    display dialog "ok" buttons {"4"} default button 1
end if
```

what I expected in this script its when I click on a element of the list , a notification start (or any other script) but I have no result.

Cheers

Comment: I have to say this is strange.  @iayork is technically correct, even though the code they posted is not correct, just their 1st line.  Jason on the other hand provides the correct answer, which is to remove the braces `{}`around  `{choose from list issueList}`, which serve no legitimate purpose, other than to double wrap the result.  Please consider re-assigning the correct answer, to avoid confusion for anyone arriving here and assuming the wrong things. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification returns {{"1"}}, not {"1"}.  Change your code to

```
if item 1 of selectedIssue is {"1"} then
```

etc and it should work.

Comment: This begs the question: Why does ```choose from list``` return a single-element list, rather than the selected element itself... as both the name implies, and as is common to most other programming languages?  Or have I missed some other equivalent feature that does this?

Comment: @RCross `choose from list` can optionally have `multiple selections allowed` so the result is always a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I got the same issue with yours, but I solved it with code like this:

```
set mailList to {"One","Two","Three","Four"}
set mailType to choose from list mailList

if item 1 of mailType is "One" then
    display dialog mailType 
else if item 1 of mailType is "Two" then
    display dialog mailType 
else if item 1 of mailType is "Three" then
    display dialog mailType 
else if item 1 of mailType is "Four" then
    display dialog mailType 
end if
```